# Determine square root of a double with series

Tags: java, math, series, square-root

The problem:

> Using the following approximate formula, write a function or method that returns the square root of a real number! Use the sequence x[k + 1] = 1/2 * (x[k] + a / x[k]), which is converges to a square root of 'a' real parameter if x1 = 1.

My solution is similar, but without using this formula:

```
public static double squareRoot(double a) {

    double k; 
    double root = a / 2;
    do {
        k = root;
        root = 0.5*(k+ (a / k));
    } while ((k - root) != 0);

    return root;`
}
```

Comment: In what sense doesn't it use that formula?

Comment: My method works, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Why do you think you haven't used the formula from the question text?

Comment: Because of the line: double root = a / 2; and the while loop. Maybe this isn't the most suitable solution.

Comment: So if you are unsure, change that to 1. Is there anything else you think might not be correct?

Comment: It works with any positive starter value. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is known as the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method). It converges for any positive initial value, so your code is correct.

However, you should return as soon as the absolute difference between consecutive values becomes less than a small value (say, 1e-10) to make sure the code ends. Otherwise there is a risk of infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the late comment. I needed this for a University project.